# ESP32 with JGY-371 stepper motor and L293D

Tags: esp32, review

I'm currently trying to make an automatic chicken coop door,
I plan to use an ESP32 with an L293D motor driver and JGY-371 geared motor 30RPM ([shop link](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B0754ZHPDS/)).
[image: motor datasheet]
The door should not exceed 1kg and should pull a 30/40 centimeter distance.The torque needed by my system should be 0.5N.m if I calculated well it should fit with the motor specification

I am planning to connect ESP32, L293D and the stepper motor using the following schematic:

[image: schematic]

Since I'm more an embedded software engineer than electronic engineer, I want to be sure if I have sourced good parts for my project and if my schematic looks correct?

Comment: There is no way for us to tell. What torque do you need to move the door, and can you see a torque specification for that motor? I can't. It's not even clear to me what type of motor that is, or how to interface to its inbuilt electronics.However it is clear that the schematic as drawn will not drive a stepper motor.

Comment: You don't want a stepper motor for this, but rather a gearmotor with limit switches.   And you don't want an L293D but rather an FET driver.  This is all doubly true if you hope to run on batteries, which will be challenging in any case.  Are you using wifi?  If not you probably don't want an ESP32 as it has very crude low power sleep modes compared to more traditional MCUs.